# Do not activate my application when activity launched by intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have utility application with two activities inside - one is main as explanation and some settings changing and second one is utility activity that is responsible for utility action itself. The utility activity has `NoWindow` theme.

I want that launching utility action from another application is not bringing my application into foreground if user still have it running.

Steps to reproduce:

1. I have activity A (launcher) and activity B (utility activity with intent filter, has `NoWindow` theme)
2. User lunches application from home screen (A is visible)
3. User navigates to another application without closing mine
4. User initiate some action that starts activity B (my app is foregrounded and presented to user but because B is `NoWindow` users sees A)

I want that when user initiate activity B he won't see activity B.

Could yo give me any advise how to achieve this? I think if I set `noHistory` flag to activity A it won't be shown but I afraid in this case if I move to activity C (About) then activity A disappears forms stack and won't be available if user presses back.

Comment: Why would you use an Activity with noWindow. you could try using a service for background stuff.

Comment: The intent filter action VIEW is only working for Activities